# What are the various interpretations of modal logic?

Tags: modal-logic

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_operator#Modality_interpreted) lists the following interpretations of modal logic:

- **Alethic:** fundamental conditions of possible worlds,  causality, time-space parameters, and the action capacity of persons. Indicates the possibility, impossibility and necessity of actions, states of affairs, events, people, and qualities in the possible worlds.
- **Deontic**
  modal operators influence the construction of possible worlds as proscriptive or prescriptive norms, i.e. they indicate what is prohibited, obligatory, or permitted.
- **Axiological**
  modal operators transform the world's entities into values and disvalues as seen by a social group, a culture, or a historical period.
- **Epistemic**
  modal operators reflect the level of knowledge, ignorance and belief in the possible world.
- **Doxastic**
  modal operators express belief in statements.

Are you aware of more?

It seems that more interpretations may be constructed through the [Categories of Being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_being).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James Garson also lists the following in his summary of modal logics which may qualify:

- [Temporal Logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#TemLog)

> In temporal logic (also known as tense logic), there are two basic operators, G for the future, and H for the past. G is read ‘it always will be that’ and the defined operator F (read ‘it will be the case that’) can be introduced by FA=∼G∼A.

- [Conditional and Relevance Logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#ConLog)

> The founder of modal logic, C. I. Lewis, defined a series of modal logics which did not have □ as a primitive symbol. Lewis was concerned to develop a logic of conditionals that was free of the so called Paradoxes of Material Implication...

- [Provability Logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#ProLog)

> Provability logics are systems where the propositional variables p,q,r, etc. range over formulas of some mathematical system, for example Peano’s system PA for arithmetic.

There may be others.

---

Garson, James, "Modal Logic", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Fall 2018 Edition), Edward N. Zalta (ed.), URL = https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/fall2018/entries/logic-modal/.